# TypeError: 'choice_text' is an invalid keyword argument for this function in django tutorial

Tags: python, django

I'm working through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/ .

Towards the end of the tutorial is a section on the django DB api there is the following:

```
# Display any choices from the related object set -- none so far.
>>> p.choice_set.all()
[]

# Create three choices.
>>> p.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not much', votes=0)
<Choice: Not much>
```

However when I directly copy : >>> p.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not much', votes=0) from the tutorial, I get:

```
raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % kw
args.keys()[0])
TypeError: 'choice_text' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

previously everything in the tut worked as expected.

Any idea what the problem is ? I'm pretty new to python coming from a php background with some OOP experience.

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you are copying directly from the tutorial. It looks like it is `choice=` instead of `choice_text=`

```
# Create three choices.
>>> p.choice_set.create(choice='Not much', votes=0)
<Choice: Not much>
>>> p.choice_set.create(choice='The sky', votes=0)
<Choice: The sky>
```

The model is:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
```

So what this line is doing is by using `choice_set.create()` ([link to docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.create)), it's creating a `Choice` model and taking the poll - `p` - and assigning that as the model field `poll` (the foreign key). And then assigning the `choice=` value to the model field `choice`, and the `votes=` value to the model field `votes`.

Comment: Hi Dan, I was looking at the dev version of the django docs!! I didn't realize there were multiple vesrions! I switched over to the 1.4 docs and fixed it. Thank you - Bill