# Django Tutorial - choice_set typeerror

Tags: python, django

So I was looking at this post to try and resolve some issues encountered in my Django tutorial:

[TypeError: 'choice_text' is an invalid keyword argument for this function in django tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737257/typeerror-choice-text-is-an-invalid-keyword-argument-for-this-function-in-dja)

this is my code:

```
from polls.models import Question, Choice
q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not much', votes=0)
q.choice_set.create(choice='Not much', votes=0)
```

I'm still facing exactly the same problem after taking the suggested solution of changing "choice_text" to "choice" - i.e exactly the same error message, and the documentation version for the Django tutorial is for Django 1.11 (my version). Does anybody know the correct syntax for creating choice sets?

Thanks!

---

Supplementary Information: My models.py file defining Question and Choice.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_texct = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: the code that i typed is:
q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not much', votes=0) and q.choice_set.create(choice='Not much', votes=0)

Comment: It's your models that you need to show. And do so as an edit to the question, not in a comment.

Comment: and add, your q query, as code to your question, don't be afraid to give more information

Comment: Apologies! Alright! Edited! Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in model:

```
choice_texct = models.CharField(max_length=200)
#      ^^^^
```

need replace

```
choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
#      ^^^^
```

and don't forget do migrations,

**Or** in your code need

```
q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not much', votes=0)
```

replace to

```
q.choice_set.create(choice_texct='Not much', votes=0)
#                          ^^^^^
```

Comment: oh gosh you're right! so sorry and thank you for your time!

Comment: glad to help you)